# There is a way to rename the controller on OnActionExecuting ASP MVC 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting

I have try to create a url rewriter according with current language. For example if I have controller Article, for each language I have a record like:

```
public class ControllerRewriter
{
    public LanguageName { get; set; }
    public NiceName { get; set; }
    public Controller { get; set; }
}
```

And also a list of ControllerRewriter where I made search.

```
public class ControllerRewriterList: List<ControllerRewriter>
{
    public string GetController(string niceName)
    {
        var cr = this.FirstOrDefault( c => c.NiceName == niceName);
        if( cr == null )
            return niceName;
        else
            return cr.Controller; 
    }
}
```

In a base Controller class I override the method OnActionExecuting in order to intercept the niceName of controller and then to rewrite it with the real name of controller, but I fail...

```
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        _actionName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName.ToLower();
        //here I get a nice name of controller according with the current language
        _controllerName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName.ToLower();

        //rewrite the controller with the real name of controller
        //this line doesn't work AND I NEED A SOLUTION ( thanks! )
        filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName = crList.GetController(_controllerName);

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
```

Do you have any idea/sugestion about how I can rewrite the controller name, here in OnActionExecuting or maybe in other method... ?

Update: RedirectToRouteResult is not an option because it will change the current url. :-)

Thanks,
Ovidiu

Comment: I think you are on the right track with the OnActionExecuting. I remember doing a switch of action and controller in (what I remebmber) was in that method a long time ago. I'll see if I can find the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(routeName, routeValues);
```

Comment: Yes I know that solution, but that will redirect me ... and it will change the current (nice) url with the "ugly one" and I don't want this.